# Cannot invoke 'location' with an argument list of type '(GameOverScene)'

Tags: ios, swift

I built an app in 2016 and now I am updating it for iOS 13 with some minor updates but I'm getting the below error.

> Cannot invoke 'location' with an argument list of type '(GameOverScene)'

Showing the above error in the code:

```
let pointOfTouch = touch.location(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Either look up the new syntax for the function, or just re-type it and let Xcode auto-fill it for you.

You'll see the new form is:

```
let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
```

Comment: *"I implemented this code but nothing happen"* --- well, that is an entirely different problem than the error you were getting. I'd suggest posting a new question with enough detail so we can see what you are trying to do.